# Howto Reverse-Engineer a REST-Webservice

Tags: php, rest, reverse-engineering

I'm currently trying to reverse-engineer a private REST-Webservice, which lacks documentation. The only thing I know about it is, that it's written in PHP, using the ZendFramework. Is there any simple way of finding out, which actions are allowed and which parameters I have to supply to make the service work correctly?

Greets,
Rob

Comment: Do you have access to the web server's log files?

Comment: This question does not detail whether you have access to a known working client of the REST API/Webservice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have an existing client using the service (a web page, mobile app, etc.) you can use a proxy to record and observe traffic that's sent/received by an existing client using the service. [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com/) will get the job done.

Comment: Chesles, can you please tell us a bit more about how Fiddler/Charles can be used to reverse engineer any REST service ? A very small example would be great. Btw, which is better in this case, charles or fiddler ? Thanks !!!

Answer (score 11):

You can use network analyzer tool like **WIRESHARK** to capture data sent on network
Read more about it on [wireshark site](https://www.wireshark.org/)

For example i hit login web service
data captured by wireshark is as:
[image]

In above image you can see data sent on HTTP protocol

**1**.) method **POST**

**2**.) Under **MIME** info
for example

*Content-Disposition: form-data; name="phoneNumber"\r\n\r\n*

name of parameter is **phoneNumber**

**===========UPDATE==============**

Here you can see fiddle captured data:

**1**.) Click on GO bottun, after that it starts capturing requests [image: Fiddle screenshot]

Comment: Can we monitor http requests and responses with chrome developer tools or do we need fiddler/wireshark/charles proxy ?

Comment: ya you can, but with wireshark you can monitor request and response of any app running on network that you are authorized to scan.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

> network analyzer tab under inspect element option in google chrome

where you can see all the data and scripts loaded for that webpage, 
for example check this screenshot, where i am trying to see which google api is used to find coordinates for the given address.
[image: example] in this you will get all the information required.