# How do I reverse engineer a rest webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, rest, google-chrome-devtools, fiddler

I have a web ui based app which I have been told, calls a rest microservice/webservice. There is no documentation for this service and there is no one who can explain the huge code to me. Moreover, the code is not self documenting.

I want to understand how the service works, by mapping the actions done on the web UI to the service calls. After googling, it seems that I can take two approaches to do that.

1 - Use chrome developer tools network module.

2 - Use fiddler or charles proxy.

Please tell me which approach is best and why. If both are not good, then please tell me how I can achieve my goal.

Thanks.

Comment: Use any of the two. Setting up Fiddler with https interception takes a few additional steps though (but it's documented).

Comment: This question is inappropriate for several reasons: you are soliciting _opinions_ about a _broad topic_.

Comment: I am not clear, do you have access to the server providing the rest service? If its a spring java rest service there are some self documenting options that will allow you to browse the available URLs, expected parameters, expected results etc... Obviously if you are purely a Rest user this is not an option.

Comment: @rmlan - I don't think so. A similar (not same) question has been asked before and I don't think it would be downvoted. Please see the question and reconsider. Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831144/howto-reverse-engineer-a-rest-webservice

Comment: @wOxxOm - I don't know which one to use. Most google searches say fiddler, wireshark or charles. None mentioned chrome dev tools. I only put that name because I had seen a tutorial on the network module of dev tools

Comment: If the app's requests show up in devtools network panel then you can obviously use it.

Comment: @GavinF - I don't have access to the server, but I have the source code. The webservice is developed using spring boot. I have never worked with Spring before.

Comment: @wOxxOm - That makes me wonder why so many tutorials recommend using fiddler or charles for reversing a rest service. Wouldn't it be simpler to just use dev tools instead. I am I missing something ?

Comment: By the way, I wonder if I really deserve downvotes for asking this question.

Comment: @testmonkey in that case you should be able to run the code locally and include the Spring Rest HAL browser, google for a few tutorials, it is very useful for testing and inspecting a rest interface!

Comment: only right to link it:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_the_hal_browser

Comment: @GavinF - Thank you. I will check out the hal browser. Btw, I was trying to map the UI actions to this webservice. Will the hal browser allow me to do that ? Suppose, I did not have the source code, then which approach would you recommend.

Comment: Personally I would use Fiddler, it is very flexible, easy to use and well documented.  Regarding the HAL Browser no its designed to drive the REST interface directly so is is completely separate to the UI, for this you would need a man in the middle solution, so Fiddler or another option would be needed!

Comment: I agree with @rmlan. Although a similar question has been asked, that doesn't mean it [belongs on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There are different ways to reverse engineer, which makes this too broad. What people think may be the "best way" is opinion based. Although it may be a good question, it's not on-topic for this site. Broad opinion-based questions result in broad opinion-based answers.

Comment: @VinceEmigh - Yes, I understand. I just need that one hint on how to approach this so that I can start doing something useful instead of endless googling. Is there any way I could make this question more specific ? Actually, I wonder why it was classified as opinion based or broad. As a beginner, it does not seem broad to me. Hope you'll understand.

Answer (score 0):

Given it has been clarified that @testmonkey has access to the source which is a spring boot rest application and the requirement is an easy way to explore and document the rest interface.  Its fair to answer that YES you could use fiddler or chrome, however given access to the source a better and more complete solution is the HAL browser:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_the_hal_browser